# Connect to FTP with Java

Tags: java, sockets, ftp

I would like to connect to a FTP from Java.

I have done this:
When the socket is connected to the FTP I get the 220 message from the socket´s inputstream (the welcome message from the FTP server).

Then I send this byte string through the sockets outputstream: "HELP".

But nothing is received from the server after sending that byte string. The inputstream is still listening but it is totaly quiet.

Have I missed something important?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send the CR/LF line terminator at the end of the command you send, e.g.

```
HELP\r\n
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to reinvent the wheel. Instead, I would recommend using Apache's [`org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient`](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html). For more information, see [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/).

Comment: I know about org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient but I would like to make my own very, very simple FTP. Just get it to connect (which I have succeeded with) to the server and send commands to it and get the replies.